# r curl curl_download doesn't append

Tags: r, curl

I'm trying to take a set of dois and have the doc.org website return the information in .bib format. The code below is supposed to do that and crucially append each new result to a .bib file. mode = a is what I understand will do the appending but it doesn't. The last line of code prints out the contents of oufFile and it contains only the last .bib results.

What needs to be changed to make this work.

```
library(curl)
outFile <- tempfile(fileext = ".bib")
url1 <- "https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tvjl.2017.12.021"
url2 <- "https://doi.org/10.1016/j.yqres.2013.10.005"
  h <- new_handle()
    handle_setheaders(h, "accept" = "application/x-bibtex")

curl_download(url1, destfile = outFile, handle = h, mode = "a")
curl_download(url2, destfile = outFile, handle = h, mode = "a")
read_delim(outFile, delim = "\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working for me as well with `curl_download()`. Alternatively you could download with `curl()` and and use `write()` with `append = TRUE`.

Here is a solution for that, which easily can be used for as many urls as you are looking to download the bibtex from. You can execute this after your line 7.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
urls <- list(url1, url2)
walk(urls, ~ {
  curl(., handle = h) %>%
    readLines(warn = FALSE) %>%
    write(file = outFile, append = TRUE)
})

library(readr)
read_delim(outFile, delim = "\n")
```

Comment: Thanks! Would be nice to have curl_download working properly. I'll post an issue in their GitHub site.

Comment: I took a brief look at the code of `curl_download()` and seems fine to me, maybe it's depending on the operating systems c++ libraries?!? I am on macOS if that helps.

Comment: Could be a mac-specific problem. I'm on one too. Catalina v10.15.3. Any way to tell what might be the offending c++ libs?